How to solve the "type 'null' is not a subtype of type object" error
I want to make a set profile page that when user must upload the profile picture, and if the upload image success it will make the auth success and redirect to homepage.But, when I run the code below, it shows the error that says "type 'null' is not a subtype of type object"
this is my model class for the Sign Up Form
class SignUpFormModel {
  final String? name;
  final String? email;
  final String? password;
  final String? profilePicture;

  SignUpFormModel({
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.profilePicture,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'username': password,
      'profile_picture': profilePicture,
    };
  }

  SignUpFormModel copyWith({
    String? profilePicture,
  }) =>
      SignUpFormModel(
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        profilePicture: profilePicture ?? this.profilePicture,
      );
}


And this is my set profile page
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/blocs/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/models/sign_up_form_model.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/shared/shared_methods.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/shared/theme.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/ui/pages/sign_up_success_page.dart';
import 'package:baca_app/ui/widgets/buttons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class SignUpSetProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final SignUpFormModel data;

  const SignUpSetProfilePage({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
  });

  @override
  State<SignUpSetProfilePage> createState() => _SignUpSetProfilePageState();
}

class _SignUpSetProfilePageState extends State<SignUpSetProfilePage> {
  XFile? selectedImage;

  selectImage() async {
    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image =
        await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = image;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthFailed) {
            showCustomSnackbar(context, state.e);
          }
          if (state is AuthSuccess) {
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context, '/home', (route) => false);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 24,
            ),
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: whiteColor,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Daftar',
                      style: opensansGreyTextStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Masukin foto profil yuk',
                      style: robotoSoftGreyTextStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: regular,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 24,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectImage();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 120,
                        height: 120,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: lightBackgroundColor,
                          image: selectedImage == null
                              ? null
                              : DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: FileImage(
                                    File(
                                      selectedImage!.path,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
                        child: selectedImage != null
                            ? null
                            : Center(
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/ic_upload.png',
                                  width: 32,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Shayna Hanna',
                      style: opensansGreyTextStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: medium,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    CustomFilledButton(
                        title: 'Continue',
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (selectedImage == null) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(
                                content: const Text(
                                  'Gambar tidak boleh kosong',
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: redColor,
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                                  AuthRegister(
                                    widget.data.copyWith(
                                      profilePicture:
                                          'data:image/png;base64,${base64Encode(File(selectedImage!.path).readAsBytesSync())}',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                          }
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I make my profilePicture fields optional but i don't understand why this error show up

is there any full error log?

sorry, but i dont know how to show the error log

where is the error indicated? does it point to any line of the code?

Please copy and paste the entire error message into your post.

Most likely the problem is in your toJson() method of the SignUpFormModel class.
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  return {
    'name': name,
    'email': email,
    'username': password,
    'profile_picture': profilePicture,
  };
}

Take note that in your toJson() method, you have ‘username’: password which appears to be the wrong way round. This is because you are placing the password value in the ‘username’ key. If your password is null and the server's requirements include a non-null username may result in erratic behavior or faults.
